# Compare to vs Compared to

Tags: grammaticality

May I know which one is grammatical?

> Method A offers a better pruning result compare to Method B.
>
> Method A  offers a better pruning result compared to Method B.

Comment: You should use "compared to".

Answer (score 1):

The full sentence is:

Method A offers a better pruning result (if/when it is) **compared** to  Method B.

Or:

If/when you **compare** Method A with  Method B, the former offers a better pruning result.

Comment: true but the reason?

Comment: Because compared is the participial form.